# Get value from dropdown in div

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Maybe this question is similar to others but I seriously can't find any solutions looking at others questions answers 
, I have a form in my view

```
<%= form_tag list_campaigns_path, :method => 'get', :id => "country_search" ,remote: true  do %>

  <%= select_tag "search_by_country", options_for_select(@country.collect { |country|
        [country.name] }, params[:search_by_country]),{ prompt: "Select country" ,id: "select_country"} %>       

  <%= submit_tag "search", class: "btn grn btn-yel"%>
<% end %>
```

what I'm trying to do is that when someone selects a country from dropdown say he selects US then after hitting on search button that selected country will be listed below with other search results that this is the country with you have performed your search.
  just a info:- i'm using `country_select` gem for getting countries list in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

To display the selected value, you have to use:

```
:selected => :search_by_country
```

in your `options_for_select`.

So, change your `select_tag` to this:

```
<%= select_tag(:search_by_country, options_for_select(@country.collect { |country|
        [country.name] }, selected: params[:search_by_country]), { prompt: "Select country", id: "select_country" })%>
```

Comment: I replaced my select tag with the one you provided but same as before nothing at all changes.

Comment: I updated a little bit. can you please try again?
`selected: params[:search_by_country]`

Comment: still the same no changes, can you please come to chat(make one i don't know how to)

Comment: Try again, made another little change. the chat option is still not appearing. usually it appears after a few comments.

Comment: Can you try without the prompt part once? Just to test.

Comment: what is the behavior now? Is it working without the selected part?

Comment: problem could be somewhere else as well. You outer form_tag is working correctly? did you test that?

Comment: I have modified your code a bit. Please try the code under the `Updated` section. Let me know if that works

Comment: Why are you using `form_tag` why not `form_for` ?

Comment: I tried your updated code now it's giving me error as i'm not using form_for
private method `select' called for nil:NilClass

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87555/discussion-between-script-kiddie-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).

Comment: hmm, can you use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`?